# About updating and testing python packages

Tags: python

I have developed some very small projects with python, with their respective packages. So, I can execute setup.py and install them. However, I dont know the proper update procedure after developing a new version, or the proper procedure for comparing the new version against the stable version. Suppose that DoTask is the name of my stable package, with a function execute

```
from DoTask import execute

if __name__ == '__main__':
    result = execute('path_to_data')
    print result
```

How can I import the new version, for comparing results? How can I update the stable version, after testing and debugging?

For example, currently I do this:

1) I give the name DevDoTask to the developing version

```
from DoTask import execute
from DevDoTask import execute as test_execute

if __name__ == '__main__':
    result = execute('path_to_data')
    test_result = test_execute('path_to_data') 
    print result == test_result
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comparing the results to those of the previous version doesn't seem like a good idea, because the previous version (although considered 'stable') can have bugs as well.

Consider creating a test suite using, for instance, the [`unittest`](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html) module. Maybe create a sample of the input data simple enough for you to know for sure what the results should be and hard-code those in the test (I don't know if it's a very good idea, but to me it looks better than comparing blindly to the previous results).

Comment: I agree with making some kind of fixtures data. However, the other most important thing is documentation (which means the specifications - input and output). Should there be dramtic changes between two versions, the tests must been rewritten. The fixtures may stay the same or modified according to the changes. Unittest at the time aren't perfect. That's why it needs system / integration test, and also tested by real users.